# The selenium webdriver test is stopped after a random number of iterations clicks

Tags: java, vb.net, selenium, automated-tests

I test a web application written in VB.NET. The application uses many nested iframes. In one of the frames is a list of items. In the second frame appear fields, which together with selecting a particular element of the first frame is filled with information retrieved from the database about this item.

I would like to create a performance test checking the time that elapses from click to load the data.

After a click when loading data appears gif-animation symbolizing this action. At this point, I check whether the animation was gone and then move on to the next click. I write code in java an my function looks like this:

```
public void function(int i, int repeat){
     for(int a = 0; a<repeat; a++){
         driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
         driver.switchTo().frame("MyFrame");
         driver.switchTo().frame("frame_Left");
         driver.switchTo().frame("Elements");

         List<WebElement> ele4 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         long start=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(ele4.get(i)));
         ele4.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("td/div/a")).click();

         driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
         driver.switchTo().frame("MyFrame");
         driver.switchTo().frame("frame_Right");
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//*[@src='/directiory/Loading.gif']"))));
         long stop=System.currentTimeMillis();  
         
         System.out.println("Time: "+(stop-start) + "\n");
         ele4.clear();
      }
}
```

At some random moment automated test stops clicking. The other actions that should be followed also stops. He does not report any errors or exceptions. When I click manually in an interesting element that makes the test resumes again.m but after a random number of iterations loop problem repeats.
How could I resolve this?

Comment: Robert : Is this happening at same line (after random number of executions in loop ) or is this occurs in different lines (different steps ) ?

Comment: The test should do this loop e.g 12 hours without any breaks. It is happening usually after hundereds loop iterations when it try to execute this line: ele4.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("td/div/a")).click();

Comment: Try to add a pause between the initial frame switch and finding the tr element. This may be caused due to a loading issue.

Comment: I wrote Thread.sleep(1000) between driver.switchTo().frame("Elements"); and
                 List<WebElement> ele4 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
Problem unfortunatelly still occures.

Comment: Robert: Since it's happening in the same line and also not throwing any exception , you could implement you own multiple click solution with some preventive mechanism for further clicking if the initial click is successful . If you like I could post a sample code but in c#

Comment: Sure! If you can, write please this sample code. I'll try to write it in java based on your idea. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted an sample code as an answer below , Please try and see whether it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I rewrite my test to C#. To my knowledge Java doesn't support click timeout. Similar code in C# doesn't freeze my program but after 60 seconds throws an exception (what is desirable in my case). What is more the same program in Java works proper on Windows 10 with a little higher version of IE (before I worked on Windows 8). I don't know why it happens, but maybe it could be clue for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This is Just sample solution** - Please try and see

```
for(int counter = 0;counter<4;counter++)
    {
     try
       { 
       // Your Code for Clicking The element i.e - ele4.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("td/div/a")).click();
       }
       catch
       {
        // If the First click is a success  second  click will throw an exception which means you have proceed to the next step
        break;
       }
    }
```

P.S - Add a Thread.Sleep() if you need more waiting time between clicks

Comment: Are you sure that the second click will throw an exception? In my case it always click many times and then goes to next steps.

Comment: Well my mistake , Since you are moving to default content I was under the impression that , Once you clicked button it will disappear(as in a pop up )  . It seems it not the case , You have to check for some new element to be appear after initial click and proceed to second click only if it is not there . I couldn't be more specific without seeing the application

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I solve my problem with another way. I presented my answer in the post.